# rotate div on parent when on click submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a wordpress submenu where the parent item has a compass attached to it, that rotates when the item is clicked. This works fine when it's used on the parent itself, but some items have a submenu.

So I am trying to solve it like this.

```
$('#menu-main-menu li.submenu li').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $('#menu-main-menu li a').addClass('disabled');
    $(this).closest('.menu-item-has-children a .compass').addClass('rotate-compass');

    link_href = this.href;

    setTimeout(function () {            
        $('body').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            window.location.href = link_href;
        }); 
    },500);

});
```

What not goes correct is the rotating part, where I attempt to add the rotate to the parent list item div. I tried it with parent, but no luck, so my second thought was to use the closest function to target it, but again no luck. What am i doing wrong here?

-edit-

[image]

I added the html structure, since i dont have a print out simply because its generated by wp, its tricky.

Comment: please show your html structure too but my guess is your closest selector is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the link and .compass are children of .menu-item-has-children. You would need to do the following:

```
$(this).closest('.menu-item-has-children').find('a .compass').addClass('rotate-compass');
```

Basically you need to find the ancestor and then drill down to find it's descendants as a separate query.

Comment: Jep that did the trick. My problem actually as well i made a new instance, of my original code, but it still took old code in account as well, so when i clicked it used the old code. I had to build an if else statement to see if the ul had a submenu attached to it, and added that to the original code. Then i could sort out the action :) works like a charm now